# Swift MacOS - Communicate with MacOS app externally

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Is there a best practice for externally communicating with MacOS apps?

I have a Rust app launched from a MacOS app via a C-Bridge and I need to let the MacOS app know when it's in the middle of a batch process.

I tried using env vars but `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` lives in it's own little world it seems. I tried writing to `Info.plist` during runtime but that didn't work either. I remember reading there was some file somewhere that had data the MacOS app could reference but I forget what that was.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Roberto from the RayWenderlich.com Discord chat for referring `URLSession` here:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

He also mentioned BSD file-sockets as well here:

- https://rderik.com/blog/using-bsd-sockets-in-swift/